# Get value from other cell on same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please see attched image. I have tried find a solution for some hours without results so now I ask. In the cells B10, C10 and D10 I want to get the value from cells in column:A in the same rows where the last given "X" is existing in each column.

For example: The last "X" in column:C is on row:6, then I want to have the value from cell A6 in the cell C10.

Is this possible with a formula?

Best regards, Vode

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH, with `Z` as the lookup value:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH("Z",B$2:B$9))
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

Posted in a comment, but in order to preserve for posterity, here is the explanation for using `Z`:

> You don't want an exact match, so you don't want to use `X`. Using `Z`, and omitting the 3rd argument of `MATCH` (meaning it defaults to `1`), means that `MATCH` finds the largest value that is less than or equal to `Z`, starting from the end, so it finds the last `X`.

Comment: Why an "Z" insteed of "X"? Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't want an exact match, so you don't want to use `X`. Using `Z`, and omitting the 3rd argument of MATCH (meaning it defaults to `1`), means that MATCH finds the largest value that is less than or equal to `Z`, starting from the end, so it finds the last `X`.